# Can't configure proxy for Python Aiogram

Tags: python, proxy, vpn, aiogram

I'm trying to create a Telegram bot with Aiogram
I live in Xi'An China where telgramm.org is blocked.

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, F
from aiogram.types import Message

token = 'tokentokentokentokentokentokentokentoken'
bot = Bot(token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(F.text == '/start')
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f'hi, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>')

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

OUTPUT:
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [The semaphore timeout period has expired]

I use vpn, and can access this site in the browser no problem

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json')
print(response.text)
print(response.json()['country'])
```

OUTPUT:
{
"ip": "212.107.30.31",
"city": "Hatsudai",
"region": "Tokyo",
"country": "JP",
"loc": "35.6652,139.6701",
"org": "AS41378 Kirino LLC",
"postal": "155-0031",
"timezone": "Asia/Tokyo",
"readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
JP

Not one of the dozens of proxy servers that i tried worked so far

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, F
from aiogram.types import Message

from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession
session = AiohttpSession(proxy="socks5://98.162.25.16:4145/")

token = '6580655645:AAHSLO3gIQTSgGkHcERE7OEAtBfBWcEf9uw'
bot = Bot(token, session=session, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(F.text == '/start')
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f'hi, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>')

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

OUTPUT:
python_socks._errors.ProxyConnectionError: [Errno 22] Couldn't connect to proxy 98.162.25.16:4145 [The semaphore timeout period has expired]

The requests module appears to just ignore proxies altogether

```
import requests

proxies = {'socks5': "socks5://98.162.25.16:4145"}

response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=proxies)
print(response.text)
print(response.json()['country'])
```

OUTPUT:
{
"ip": "212.107.30.31",
"city": "Hatsudai",
"region": "Tokyo",
"country": "JP",
"loc": "35.6652,139.6701",
"org": "AS41378 Kirino LLC",
"postal": "155-0031",
"timezone": "Asia/Tokyo",
"readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
JP